# extract keys of json schema without building json data

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have huge JSON schema(not JSON data) and want to extract keys out of it.

I have sample JSON schema like shown below. I cannot post the actual schema owing to its size.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {},
  "id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "properties": {
    "checked": {
      "id": "/properties/checked",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "id": {
      "id": "/properties/id",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "id": "/properties/name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "price": {
      "id": "/properties/price",
      "type": "number"
    },
    "tags": {
      "id": "/properties/tags",
      "items": {
        "id": "/properties/tags/items",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

Given this schema how will I be able to extract keys as shown in JSON below.The below JSON object is JSON data which has all keys so mentioned in JSON schema.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "A green door",
  "price": 12.5,
  "checked": false,
  "tags": [
    "home",
    "green"
  ]
}
```

I have tried **JSON schema faker** but that produces different data every time.It even produces empty object sometimes and **I cannot manually modify the JSON schema** as its huge. I want all the keys to be there. For example in the above schema,I should be able to extract all the keys below.

1. id
2. name
3. price
4. checked
5. tags

   - home
   - green.

I tried recursive solution but that did not help. Any solution of how will I be able to build JSON data which has all keys mentioned in schema using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.I hope this will help you to achieve your use-case.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class regexExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
       String jsonstr="{\n" +
               "  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n" +
               "  \"definitions\": {},\n" +
               "  \"id\": \"http://example.com/example.json\",\n" +
               "  \"properties\": {\n" +
               "    \"checked\": {\n" +
               "      \"id\": \"/properties/checked\",\n" +
               "      \"type\": \"boolean\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    \"id\": {\n" +
               "      \"id\": \"/properties/id\",\n" +
               "      \"type\": \"integer\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    \"name\": {\n" +
               "      \"id\": \"/properties/name\",\n" +
               "      \"type\": \"string\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    \"price\": {\n" +
               "      \"id\": \"/properties/price\",\n" +
               "      \"type\": \"number\"\n" +
               "    },\n" +
               "    \"tags\": {\n" +
               "      \"id\": \"/properties/tags\",\n" +
               "      \"items\": {\n" +
               "        \"id\": \"/properties/tags/items\",\n" +
               "        \"type\": \"string\"\n" +
               "      },\n" +
               "      \"type\": \"array\"\n" +
               "    }\n" +
               "  },\n" +
               "  \"type\": \"object\"\n" +
               "}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[\\w]+\":");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonstr);
        String result="";
        while (m.find( )) {
            result = m.group().replace("\"","");
            result = result.replace(":","");
            System.out.println("Found value: " + result );
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me the same in javascript as I am using this in react js?

Comment: Can we produce JSON data out of it as shown in above example?

Answer (score -2):

```
function myFunction() {
var str = { "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",         "definitions": {}, "id": "http://example.com/example.json",  "properties": {    "checked": {      "id": "/properties/checked",      "type": "boolean"    },    "id": {      "id": "/properties/id",      "type": "integer"    },    "name": {      "id": "/properties/name",      "type": "string"    },    "price": {      "id": "/properties/price",      "type": "number"    },    "tags": {      "id": "/properties/tags",      "items": {        "id": "/properties/tags/items",        "type": "string"      },      "type": "array"    }  },  "type": "object"};
for (var key in str) {
       console.log(key);
       for(var key1 in key) {
       console.log(key);
       }
   }
}
```

This will get key's of key.If you want to get all the keys then you need to write recursive method.